# Im looking to only have one alert per trend not every cross on a horizontal line script

Tags: pine-script

I have a horizontal line script and when the ma crosses a horizontal line it trades but it continues to trade on every cross. Im only a copy and paste coder and the guy i paid to help me has made it beyond my knowledge limit.I have tried to get it going with pasting similar code but just dont understand enuff.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//@version=5
// please continue to use the black gold name so all can follow the progress of this idea
// black gold slang for crude oil
// have been testing on oil 1m chart
// ive been placing the midline on a resistance line  // 
// @oiltanker
indicator(title="BLACK GOLD ma trigger ", overlay=true)



valMedian   = input(defval=68.60, title="Median Value")
valOffset   = input(defval=0.10, title="Offset Value")

// offset multiplier function.
offsetMult(num) => num * valOffset

// Plot median line
midline     = plot(valMedian, title="Median Line", color=#905d8a, linewidth=2)

// ..colour and transparency variables for quicker 'style' edits..
_dc = #5b5e5f
_dt = 50
// plot upward offsets
plus1   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(1), title="Plus 1", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus2   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(2), title="Plus 2", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus3   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(3), title="Plus 3", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus4   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(4), title="Plus 4", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus5   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(5), title="Plus 5", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus6   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(6), title="Plus 6", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus7   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(7), title="Plus 7", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus8   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(8), title="Plus 8", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus9   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(9), title="Plus 9", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus10  = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(10), title="Plus 10", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus11   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(11), title="Plus 11", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus12   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(12), title="Plus 12", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus13   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(13), title="Plus 13", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus14   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(14), title="Plus 14", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus15   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(15), title="Plus 15", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus16   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(16), title="Plus 16", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus17   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(17), title="Plus 17", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus18   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(18), title="Plus 18", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus19   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(19), title="Plus 19", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus20   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(20), title="Plus 20", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus21   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(21), title="Plus 10", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus22   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(22), title="Plus 11", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus23   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(23), title="Plus 12", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus24   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(24), title="Plus 13", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
plus25   = plot(valMedian + offsetMult(25), title="Plus 14", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
// plot downward offsets
minus1   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(1), title="minus 1", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus2   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(2), title="minus 2", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus3   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(3), title="minus 3", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus4   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(4), title="minus 4", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus5   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(5), title="minus 5", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus6   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(6), title="minus 6", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus7   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(7), title="minus 7", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus8   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(8), title="minus 8", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus9   = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(9), title="minus 9", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus10  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(10), title="minus 10", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus11  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(11), title="minus 11", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus12  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(12), title="minus 12", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus13  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(13), title="minus 13", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus14  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(14), title="minus 14", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus15  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(15), title="minus 15", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus16  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(16), title="minus 16", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus17  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(17), title="minus 17", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus18  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(18), title="minus 18", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus19  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(19), title="minus 19", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus20  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(20), title="minus 20", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus21  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(21), title="minus 10", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus22  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(22), title="minus 11", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus23  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(23), title="minus 12", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus24  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(24), title="minus 13", color=_dc, linewidth=1)
minus25  = plot(valMedian - offsetMult(25), title="minus 14", color=_dc, linewidth=1)

//vwap ma
len = input.int(6, "Length", minval=1)
src = input(close, "Source")
ma = ta.vwma(src, len)
plot(ma, title="VWMA", color=#ec0f17, linewidth=3)

//vwap ma2
len2 = input.int(2, "Length", minval=1)
src2 = input(close, "Source")
ma2 = ta.vwma(src2, len2)
//plot(ma2, title="VWMA2", color=#71d316, linewidth=3)
up_trend =  (ma2[1] < ma2) 
dn_trend =  ( ma2[1] > ma2) 


up= (up_trend ) ? 1:na
dn= ( dn_trend) ? -1:na

sig=0
if up==1
    sig:=1
else
    if dn==-1
        sig:=-1
    else
        sig:=sig[1]



//alerts
method alert_cross_plus(int index) =>
    cross_up = ta.crossover( ma, valMedian + offsetMult(index))
    cross_down = ta.crossunder( ma, valMedian + offsetMult(index))
    if cross_up
        alert("LONG | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD c=position b=sell t=market | delay=3  | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD b=buy q=100 ts=-0.25 t=market ") 
    else if cross_down
        alert(" SHORT|  e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD c=position b=buy t=market | delay=3  | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD b=sell q=100 ts=0.25  t=market")

method alert_cross_minus(int index) =>
    cross_up = ta.crossover( ma, valMedian - offsetMult(index)) 
    cross_down =  ta.crossunder( ma, valMedian - offsetMult(index)) 
    if cross_up
        alert(" LONG | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD c=position b=sell t=market | delay=3  | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD b=buy q=100  ts=-0.25  t=market ")
    else if cross_down
        alert(" SHORT|  e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD c=position b=buy t=market | delay=3  | e=oandapractice a=DEMO s=WTICO_USD b=sell q=100  ts=-0.25 t=market ")

alert_cross_plus(1)
alert_cross_plus(2)
alert_cross_plus(3)
alert_cross_plus(4)
alert_cross_plus(5)
alert_cross_plus(6)
alert_cross_plus(7)
alert_cross_plus(8)
alert_cross_plus(9)
alert_cross_plus(10)
alert_cross_plus(11)
alert_cross_plus(12)
alert_cross_plus(13)
alert_cross_plus(14)
alert_cross_plus(15)
alert_cross_plus(16)
alert_cross_plus(17)
alert_cross_plus(18)
alert_cross_plus(19)
alert_cross_plus(20)
alert_cross_plus(21)
alert_cross_plus(22)
alert_cross_plus(23)
alert_cross_plus(24)
alert_cross_plus(25)
alert_cross_plus(26)
alert_cross_plus(27)
alert_cross_plus(28)
alert_cross_plus(29)
alert_cross_plus(30)
alert_cross_plus(31)
alert_cross_plus(32)
alert_cross_plus(33)
alert_cross_plus(34)
alert_cross_plus(35)
alert_cross_plus(36)
alert_cross_plus(37)
alert_cross_plus(38)
alert_cross_plus(39)
alert_cross_plus(40)
alert_cross_plus(41)
alert_cross_plus(42)
alert_cross_plus(43)
alert_cross_plus(44)
alert_cross_plus(45)
alert_cross_plus(46)
alert_cross_plus(47)
alert_cross_plus(48)
alert_cross_plus(49)
alert_cross_plus(50)
alert_cross_plus(51)
alert_cross_plus(52)
alert_cross_plus(53)
alert_cross_plus(54)
alert_cross_plus(55)
alert_cross_plus(56)

alert_cross_minus(1)
alert_cross_minus(2)
alert_cross_minus(3)
alert_cross_minus(4)
alert_cross_minus(5)
alert_cross_minus(6)
alert_cross_minus(7)
alert_cross_minus(8)
alert_cross_minus(9)
alert_cross_minus(10)
alert_cross_minus(11)
alert_cross_minus(12)
alert_cross_minus(13)
alert_cross_minus(14)
alert_cross_minus(15)
alert_cross_minus(16)
alert_cross_minus(17)
alert_cross_minus(18)
alert_cross_minus(19)
alert_cross_minus(20)
alert_cross_minus(21)
alert_cross_minus(22)
alert_cross_minus(23)
alert_cross_minus(24)
alert_cross_minus(25)
alert_cross_minus(26)
alert_cross_minus(27)
alert_cross_minus(28)
alert_cross_minus(29)
alert_cross_minus(30)
alert_cross_minus(31)
alert_cross_minus(32)
alert_cross_minus(33)
alert_cross_minus(34)
alert_cross_minus(35)
alert_cross_minus(36)
alert_cross_minus(37)
alert_cross_minus(38)
alert_cross_minus(39)
alert_cross_minus(40)
alert_cross_minus(41)
alert_cross_minus(42)
alert_cross_minus(43)
alert_cross_minus(44)
alert_cross_minus(45)
alert_cross_minus(46)
alert_cross_minus(47)
alert_cross_minus(48)
alert_cross_minus(49)
alert_cross_minus(50)
alert_cross_minus(51)
alert_cross_minus(52)
alert_cross_minus(53)
alert_cross_minus(54)
alert_cross_minus(55)
//END
```

Comment: Others things im looking at are, arrows on trades , strategy and adding other conditions.  Finding it so hard with the code this guy wrote.

Comment: I dont think the median line works either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have one alert by trade, pinescript must trade.
So you must transform your indicator in a strategy.
Then in your alert's condition, you will be able to add the condition :

```
strategy.opentrades == 0
```

which will prevent a new alert if a trade is already in progress.